# Javascript Function Not Stopping Button.Click ASP.Net Code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have been frustrated today with what seems like an easy piece of code. I cannot seem to get the OnClientClick to not run the ASP.net code if I try to use a custom Javascript function. However if I use just the standard "javascript:return confirm('whatever')" that will stop the submit if I click cancel. Can you help me to understand why my custom function is not working to do the same thing?

Here is the code for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmitChanges" runat="server" Text="Submit Changes" Class="justround" autofocus="autofocus" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:myCustomConfirm()"/>
```

Here is the VB.Net Function that handles the button click:

```
    Protected Sub ButtonSubmitChanges_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSubmitChanges.Click

    Dim ChangeErrorMessage As String = SubmitChanges()

    If ChangeErrorMessage.Length <= 0 Then

        Response.Redirect("ViewChangeRequest.aspx?CRID=" & ChangeRequest_ID.ToString)
    Else
        labelSystemMessage.Text = ChangeErrorMessage
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is the customer Javascript function:

```
function myCustomConfirm() {

return confirm("Are you sure?");
}
```

Again, why will it stop the onclick with the normal return confirm() and click Cancel, but not stop the code when I use my function and click cancel?

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe you need to use AutoWireup="false" in your .aspx.

Comment: You're not returning the value returned by "myCustomConfirm()". You're just calling it and throwing away the result.

Comment: Oh my goodness, it was so simple that I want to bash my head against the keyboard. Thank you @Pointy I knew it seemed too difficult....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a `return` in the OnClientClick handler.

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmitChanges" runat="server" 
Text="Submit Changes" Class="justround" autofocus="autofocus"    
OnClientClick="javascript:return myCustomConfirm()"/>
```

Comment: Geez, I knew it was something simple, but now I just feel ridiculous. Thank you so much @AricTenEyck!